# How to Update filename based highest value of files names from other two columns

Tags: c#, wpf, filenames

i need to update the filename based on the highest name of filename from other two columns.
For ex:- I have coumn3 called `221-8812_01` and column4 called `221-8812_02`. So i want to update the `221-8812_02` file name to the column1.

Vise versa, if i have a file name called `323-1111_03` in column3 and `323-1111_02` in column3, so i want to update 323-1111_03 in column1.

**Note:-
 I have filename like 323-2332_0A and 323-2332_0B. so i need to update 323-2332_0B in column1.
or may be 111-4334_0D and 111-4334_0C** so i need update `111-4334_0D` to column1.

So its like **first sever number remains the same. after seven numbers.. when the (_)Underscore starts.. i need to compare.. according to alphabets or numbers in increasing order**!!!!
How can i do this,

My codes snippet:

```
 private void filter_table()
    {
 // create a check box in column0
        DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn colCB = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
        DatagridViewCheckBoxHeaderCell cbHeader = new DatagridViewCheckBoxHeaderCell();
        colCB.HeaderCell = cbHeader;
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(colCB);


        //Initialize Directory path
        string draft = ini.ReadValue("Location", "Draft");
        string release = ini.ReadValue("Location", "Release");
        string drawing = ini.ReadValue("Location", "Drawing");
        string archive = ini.ReadValue("Location", "Archive");

        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(draft))
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(draft);
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(release))
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(release);
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(drawing))
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(drawing);
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(archive))
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(archive);

        string[] arrDraft = Directory.GetFiles(draft, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        string[] arrRelease = Directory.GetFiles(release, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        string[] arrDrawing = Directory.GetFiles(drawing, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        string[] arrArchive = Directory.GetFiles(archive, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        dt.Columns.Add("Drawing_Number");
        //dt.Columns["Part Number"].ReadOnly = true;

        dt.Columns.Add("Drawing");
        // dt.Columns["Drawing"].ReadOnly = true;

        dt.Columns.Add("Draft Path");
        // dt.Columns["Draft Path"].ReadOnly = true;

        dt.Columns.Add("Release Path");
        //  dt.Columns["Release Path"].ReadOnly = true;

        dt.Columns.Add("Error");
        //  dt.Columns["Error"].ReadOnly = true;

        dt.Columns.Add("Archive");

   // listing all the files according to the column3(draft path) filename.. and mating files from nearby column.
        List<FileDetails> lst = new List<FileDetails>();
        foreach (string file in arrDraft)
        {
            Finder finder = new Finder(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file).Substring(0, 7));
            string abc = Array.Find(arrRelease, finder.Match);
            string cdf = Array.Find(arrDrawing, finder.Match);
            string ghi = Array.Find(arrArchive, finder.Match);
            dt.Rows.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file), cdf, file, abc, String.Empty, ghi);
        }

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }

  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        filter_table();
   }

   // Search predicate returns true if a string ends in "saurus".
    private static bool MatchFileName(String s, String _match)
    {
        return ((s.Length > 5) && (s.Substring(0, 7).ToLower() == _match.ToLower()));
    }


    public class FileDetails
    {
        public string FileName;
        public string Drawings;
        public string FilePathDraft;
        public string FilePathRelease;
        public string Comment;
        public string ErrorMsg;
    }
    public sealed class Finder
    {
        private readonly string _match;

        public Finder(string match)
        {
            _match = match.ToLower();
        }

   //findin the match and showing in grid view
        public bool Match(string s)
        {
            string fileName = s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
            return ((fileName.Length > 5) && (fileName.Substring(0, 8).ToLower() == _match));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why is `323-2332_0B` “higher” than `323-2332_0A` but `111-4334_0C` is higher than `111-4334_0D`?

Comment: @DourHighArch i am looking for _0A, 0B, 0C.. go goes on. to 0Z.. while in numbers it goes like _01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07 .. loping for the last two numbers

Comment: What you need is a method (or an implementation of IComparable) that can compare 2 strings and return the one that is "higher". We can't help you with the comparison logic because as @DourHighArch points out above, your comparison logic does not make much sense. i.e. B > A but C > D. Once you know the result of which string is higher, you can then proceed to update whichever column you need.

Comment: @failedprogramming i have specified the reason which is higher.. i am looking for last two values.._0A, 0B, 0C.. goes on. to 0Z.. while in numbers it goes like _01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07 .. looking for the last two numbers

Comment: @StacyKebler I know you specified the reason, but I am saying it does not make sense to me. Between 323-2332_0B and 323-2332_0A, you say that 323-2332_0B is higher. That makes sense if it is because the numbers are the same and B comes after A in the alphabet. However, between 111-4334_0C and 111-4334_0D, you say that 111-4334_0C is higher. That does not make any sense since the numbers are the same and D comes after C in the alphabet.

Comment: @failedprogramming sorry that was a mistake.. between 111-4334_0C and 111-4334_0D,  111-4334_0D is higher.. cheers!!!!!.. it goes like as u said... numbers first 7 numbers same.. then after underscore.. i want to compare

Comment: @failedprogramming sorry for the mis lead!! I have updated the question.. please have a look.. Sorry for that!!!

Comment: @DourHighArch sorry for the mis lead!! I have updated the question.. please have a look.. Sorry for that!!!.. I need to update in this way!!!! Please update the answer.. so that i can accept it.. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Stacy your question was very hard to understand because of the mistake. You tagged your question as `WPF` and `filenames` but those have nothing to do with the problem. Also, your code has nothing to do with the problem. Please make the effort to only include information relevant to the question or people will be mislead.

Comment: @DourHighArch ok sorry about that!! peace!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's make it easy

```
string A = "323-1111_0A";
string B = "323-1111_0D";
MessageBox.Show(TakeLarger(A, B));

private string TakeLarger(string first, string second)
{
    int iResult = first.Substring(first.LastIndexOf("_")+1).CompareTo(second.Substring(second.LastIndexOf("_")+1));

    return (iResult == -1) ? second : first;
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
323-1111_0D
```

---

if the last two digit is Hexadecimal value then you can use this method.

```
string A = "323-1111_FF";
string B = "323-1111_1D";
MessageBox.Show(TakeLarger(A, B));

private string TakeLargerHex(string first, string second)
{
    int iFirst = Convert.ToInt32(first.Substring(first.LastIndexOf("_")+1), 16);
    int iSecond = Convert.ToInt32(second.Substring(second.LastIndexOf("_")+1), 16);
    return (iFirst > iSecond) ? first : second;
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
323-1111_FF
```

if the file name is stord in your grid cell like `MY_FILE_323-1111_FF.doc` then you need to remove the extension from the end otherwise you can take directly.

```
string A = dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
string B = dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
```

if the extension is included at the end of the string then you can remove like this.

```
A = A.Substring(A.LastIndexOf(".")+1);
```

Comment: how to incorporate in my above code... Also it should be in a such a way.. that numbers. it continues till 1000.. like 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14,, like this.. till 1000. Also alphabets. like 0A, 0B, 0C, 0D, 0E, 0F.. like that till 0Z.. if 0Z comes then,, it should go to .. 1A, 1B, 1C, 1D, 1E. till 1Z.. if 1Z number and alphabet reached.. then the file numbers may continue as.. 2A..2 B, 2C,, like that.. could u make it such a way

Comment: Do you mean that value can be like `323-2332_1000` or `323-2332_1Z`?

Comment: If the value is 00 to 09 and A0 to FF then its a Hexadecimal value its not a string. In this case you need to use the second method. If the value can be more than `F` for example 1G, 2L, 9Z then its string value. In this case you can use first method.

Comment: we have lot of file names shell. in future we have file names upto starting from 00 to 100000. and our old file names are like.. starting from 0A and and it may goes upto 9Z.

Comment: then you should try first method.

Comment: I mean how will i code for `dt.Rows.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file), cdf, file, abc, String.Empty, ghi);` this line

Answer (score 1):

I have knocked up a quick and simple method to compare 2 strings and determine which is higher, according to your logic.

**Please note:**

- **You probably want to modify this code and implement IComparable instead**
- **if you prefer to use the code as a static method like below, you will need to handle the situation where both strings are equal**
- **If you are confident the first 7 numbers are always the same, you can omit that logic**
- **My logic assumes that positions are fixed. If positions are dynamic, you will need to modify the code to search for the underscore using string.IndexOf("_")**

  ```
  // returns true if a is "higher" than b
  // example string format 323-2332_0A
  private static bool IsHigher(string a, string b)
  {
      if(string.CompareOrdinal(a.ToUpper(), b.ToUpper()) == 0)
          throw new InvalidOperationException("The strings are equal!");

      // Compare first 3 numbers
      var inta = Convert.ToInt32(a.Substring(0, 3));
      var intb = Convert.ToInt32(b.Substring(0, 3));
      var result = inta.CompareTo(intb);

      if (result > 0) return true; // a is "higher" than b
      if (result < 0) return false; // b is "higher" than a
      // if a = b, code continues down ...

      // Compare middle 4 numbers
      inta = Convert.ToInt32(a.Substring(4, 4));
      intb = Convert.ToInt32(b.Substring(4, 4));
      result = inta.CompareTo(intb);

      if (result > 0) return true; // a is "higher" than b
      if (result < 0) return false; // b is "higher" than a
      // if a = b, code continues down ...

      // Compare last number
      inta = Convert.ToInt32(a.Substring(9, 1));
      intb = Convert.ToInt32(b.Substring(9, 1));
      result = inta.CompareTo(intb);

      if (result > 0) return true; // a is "higher" than b
      if (result < 0) return false; // b is "higher" than a
      // if a = b, code continues down ...

      // Compare alphabet
      var stringa = a.Substring(10, 1).ToUpper();
      var stringb = b.Substring(10, 1).ToUpper();
      result = String.CompareOrdinal(stringa, stringb);

      if (result > 0) return true; // a is "higher" than b
      if (result < 0) return false; // b is "higher" than a

      return true; // we should not get here.

  }
  ```

**Edit**

You would probably use this code before adding the row to the datagrid.

For example, if you wanted to compare the strings with the current filename, and only choose the "higher" one, you would do this.

```
Finder finder = new Finder(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file).Substring(0, 7));
string abc = Array.Find(arrRelease, finder.Match);
string cdf = Array.Find(arrDrawing, finder.Match);
string ghi = Array.Find(arrArchive, finder.Match);
var filenameonly = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
dt.Rows.Add(filenameonly, 
            IsHigher(filenameonly, cdf) ? filenameonly : cdf, 
            file, 
            IsHigher(filenameonly, abc) ? filenameonly : abc, 
            String.Empty, 
            IsHigher(filenameonly, ghi) ? filenameonly : ghi
           );
```

Comment: Actully could you edit.. this program in a such a way.. numbers. it continues till 1000.. like 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14,, like this.. till 1000. Also alphabets. like 0A, 0B, 0C, 0D, 0E, 0F.. like that till 0Z.. if 0Z comes then,, it should go to .. 1A, 1B, 1C, 1D, 1E. till 1Z.. if 1Z number and alphabet reached.. then the file numbers may continue as.. 2A..2 B, 2C,, like that..

Comment: @StacyKebler I believe what I have given you is enough to put you on the right track. As I mentioned in my answer, if your character positions are dynamic, you will need to use string.IndexOf() to find the positions of the underscore/hyphen. Once you have that, you can use the string.Substring() method to slice the required part.

Comment: @StacyKebler please see my edit. I have explained how you can use this code.

Comment: let me check and tell u